# Vtiger CRM: How I can load modified .tpl file?

Tags: file, crm, vtiger

I want to load a modified .tpl file vtigercrm\layouts\vlayout\modules\Vtiger\ListViewContents.tpl to a .php file from which I get HTML data after using AJAX and javascript . It's something feasible?

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming that you want to view that template in the DetailView. In that case you can make a widget in module/Vtiger/models/DetailView.php in getWidget(). Just copy paste and change. The link you give here should go to a function in /module/Vtiger/views/Detail.php.

you should add your new function in the constructor.

```
$this->exposeMethod('Yourfunctionname');
```

Here you can copy any function and change it. you need to feed your variables to smarty with :

```
$viewer->assign('SMARTYVARNAME', $phpVar);
```

to fill the template. And finally you need to referance the template.

```
echo $viewer->view('tplname.tpl', $moduleName, 'true');
```

im not able to comment yet so i hope this is enough.